# Gradle Plugin is not found

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

As you can see, the plugin [id: 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention', version: '0.4.0'] is not found, and I don't understand why. I am working on this project with other colleagues. The Gradle build works for them. We have analyzed our classes, and they are identical. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySIGD.png)

I have cloned the project from the repository several times, but with no success. Furthermore, my colleagues have sent me their project folder, but that doesn't work for me either. Finally, I tried creating a new test project, adding Gradle from IntelliJ right away, and it works in this case.The environment variables appear to be correct.

Comment: Does it work out of IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have installed Gradle correctly on your machine? Check in the terminal using 'gradle -version

Comment: Yes, I'm. I'm using Gradle 8.3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).